# Is this server missing the kvm kernel module?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, kernel-modules

Is this server missing the KVM kernel module? (I ask because KVM isn't working properly, VMs are starting and freezing at BIOS)

```
root@box:~# lsmod | grep kvm
root@box:~# 
root@box:~# /etc/init.d/qemu-kvm start
Loading kvm module kvm_intel.
root@box:~# lsmod | grep kvm
root@box:~# 
root@box:~# modprobe kvm_intel
root@box:~# lsmod | grep kvm
root@box:~#
```

On another box I have running KVM;

```
root@box2:~# lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel             115159  0 
kvm                   291655  1 kvm_intel
root@box2:~#
```

Am I missing the KVM kernel module, or is this not how it should be loaded? If I am missing it, I assume I need to recompile the Kernel to get it back, is that correct?

```
root@box:~# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l

root@box:~# uname -a
Linux box1 3.4.9 #1 SMP Mon Sep 3 17:09:07 BST 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much log searching and sifting, I found one entry (in dmesg
 after a reboot) that said something like "Loading KVM Kernel module... Stopped (or disallowed) by BIOS".

Virtual extensions where turned off in the BIOS, I never do that so I never checked it.